# CMAKE logical expressions combined "STREQUAL" and "OR"

Tags: cmake

Please correct the usage of logical expressions

```
$<$<STREQUAL:${VARIANT},abc>or>$<$<STREQUAL:${VARIANT},xyz>:service::accept_service>
```

Here am trying to check if the variant is either "abc" or "xyz" based on that service::accept_service is enabled.
There is a syntax mistake in combining STREQUAL and OR expressions which am not able to figure.

Comment: You ask us about construction which is suitable for your purpose, but seems you forgot to describe that **purpose**. What **meaning** of the generator expression do you want to achieve?

Comment: updated, pls check

Comment: As you could find in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:OR),  the syntax of OR expression is `$<OR:cond1, cond2>`. This differs drastically from your attempt `...or>`. For check whether string is equal to **one of values**, you could find expression [IN_LIST](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:IN_LIST) to be simpler: `<$IN_LIST:${VARIANT},abc;xyz>`.

Comment: I tried this $<$<OR:(${VARIANT} STREQUAL abc),(${VARIANT} STREQUAL xyz)>:service::accept_service>  got en error which says alias target missing. Could you pls correct if am missing anything

Comment: Why are you trying to put operators (`OR`, `STREQUAL`) between their arguments? In generator expression any operator is placed at the **beginning** of `$<..>`, is followed by colon (`:`) and only after it operands are listed. E.g. `$<STREQUAL:${VARINIT},abc>` compares the string with `abc`. If you want to use result of one operation in some other operation, then use whole that **operation as an operand**: `$<OR: $<STREQUAL:${VARINIT},abc>,$<STREQUAL:${VARINIT},xyz>>`.

Answer (score 0):

$<$<OR:$<STREQUAL:${VARIANT},abc>,$<STREQUAL:${VARIANT},xyz>>:service::accept_service>

This worked, thank you @tsyvarev for your help.